# How to write PDM rules for xml using xpath expressions in Sonar?

Tags: sonarqube

I want to write a XPATH rule in sonar to check whether some xml tag is present are not for a custom xml. If not available sonar should show as bug.

Thanks in Advance

Thanks for Reply. I am trying to write XPATH Rule in sonar. Here is XML ..

```
<root>
    <child1 name =”test” > …………….. </child1>
    <child2 name =”test2”> ………….. </child2> 
</root>
```

Here is my Xpath expression :

```
/child2
```

This is working fine. This node is identified by sonar. Sonar giving violation if it finds **child2** node.

Now I want to show a violation if I doesn’t find **child1** node. 
I am trying below XPATH expression but its failing.

```
not(boolean(/child1))
```

And also I want to know **name** attribute is exists or not in **child1** node. 
Please help me … 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To do so, you should not use the PMD plugin but rather the [XML plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/XML+Plugin) with its "XPath rule" (see [this rule on Nemo](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/rules_configuration/index/146?commit=Search&rule_activation=&searchtext=xpath&sort_by=SORT_BY_RULE_NAME)).

Comment: Thanks for Reply.
I am trying to write XPATH Rule in sonar. 
Here is XML ..
`<root>
<child1  name =”test” >
 ……………..
</child1>
<child2  name  =”test2”>
 …………..
</child2>
</root>`
Here is my Xpath expression :
This is working fine. Its identified by sonar. It is giving violation If it finds **child2** node. 
`//child2`
Now I want to give violation if I don’t find **child1** node. I am trying below XPATH expression but its failing.
`Not(Boolean(//child2))`
And also I want to know  **name** attribute is exists or not in **child2** node.
Please help me … Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question (or create a new question) to add details, because it is unreadable in a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I have added more info.